# Conic's connection in projective space

Tags: general-topology, projective-geometry, quadrics

How to show that a conic/quadric in the projective space $\mathbb P^n$ (real or complex, dimension $n>1$) is connected.

Comment: ... in dimension $>1$.

Comment: Yes, of course.